# Can't retrieve entity config: blog/eav_attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configuration

Can't retrieve entity ***config: blog/eav_attribute***

My magento site showing error when go to product details.

*Please suggest me how to remove this error*

Answer (score 0):

**Can't retrieve entity config: blog/eav_attribute**

This error because of,you have ***an attribute  or a system configuration setting  field***  which a  model class *(for `attribute`,it may `backend model,frontend_model,attribute_model,source_model` and for system configuration field it may be  `backend model,frontend model` etc)*.

is taken from a model type `blog/eav_attribute`.

But as this **model type's module** does not exits at  system that why it thown the error.

*For a solution you need to this attribute fro system. by running  below code.*

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE 'source_model'='blog/eav_attribute';
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE 'backend_model'='blog/eav_attribute';
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE 'frontend_model'='blog/eav_attribute';
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE 'attribute_model'='blog/eav_attribute';
```

***Note: that you should take database backup,before running above queries .***

Comment: Yes it could be work .